# How do I serve simple flat file from IIS

Tags: iis

I am tryin to set up a subordinate Windows Ca where the root Ca is OpenSSL.

I added a couple of lines to my OpenSSL.CHF file before signing the Subordinates Certificate as per: https://blog.ronnyvdb.net/2019/01/20/can-ms-certificate-services-be-a-subordinate-enterprise-ca-beneath-a-root-ca-created-with-openssl/

Now I need to be serving root.pem and root.Crl

As:

http://root-ca.mydomain.local/root.pem

http://root-ca.mydomain.local/root.crl

I have adjusted the handlers on the Default web site in IIS and added simple handlers - one for each type: *.pem and *.crl

When I restart IIS and try to download the file I get error:

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
> the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
> information about the error and where it originated in the code.

I don’t know the first thing about IIS to be honest and have tended to hate it over the years. Any help appreciated.

Comment: If they are static files, you don't need any changes on handlers, but add new extensions to MIME types, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/staticcontent/mimemap

Comment: You can use FRT to troubleshoot this issue: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis